# Pip gives error when installing vpnotebook

Tags: python, pip, vpython

Vpython versions are not available from their website, but according to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vpython-users/AmIZF2v4Wkc, "pip install vpython" should work for any version of Python.
I entered "pip install vpython" into the windows command prompt. After several minutes of downloading, pip gave me the following error:

```
  Running setup.py install for vpnotebook ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\zachary\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Zachary\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-dx_wvbg0\\vpnotebook\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Zachary\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-3q5u2e2l-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    ImportError install_kernel_spec
    c:\users\zachary\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:331: UserWarning: Normalizing '0.1.03' to '0.1.3'
      normalized_version,
    running install
    Installing Python module...
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib
    creating build\lib\vpnotebook
    copying vpnotebook\__init__.py -> build\lib\vpnotebook
    creating build\lib\vpnotebook\data
    copying vpnotebook\data\kernel.json -> build\lib\vpnotebook\data
    running install_lib
    creating c:\users\zachary\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\site-packages\vpnotebook
    creating c:\users\zachary\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\site-packages\vpnotebook\data
    copying build\lib\vpnotebook\data\kernel.json -> c:\users\zachary\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\site-packages\vpnotebook\data
    copying build\lib\vpnotebook\__init__.py -> c:\users\zachary\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\site-packages\vpnotebook
    byte-compiling c:\users\zachary\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\site-packages\vpnotebook\__init__.py to __init__.cpython-36.pyc
    running install_egg_info
    running egg_info
    writing vpnotebook.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to vpnotebook.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to vpnotebook.egg-info\top_level.txt
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

    reading manifest file 'vpnotebook.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    writing manifest file 'vpnotebook.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    Copying vpnotebook.egg-info to c:\users\zachary\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\site-packages\vpnotebook-0.1.3-py3.6.egg-info
    running install_scripts
    writing list of installed files to 'C:\Users\Zachary\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-3q5u2e2l-record\install-record.txt'
    Installing custom kernel ...
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Zachary\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-dx_wvbg0\vpnotebook\setup.py", line 30, in <module>
        package_data={'vpnotebook': ['data/kernel.json']},
      File "c:\users\zachary\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\users\zachary\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\users\zachary\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\Zachary\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-dx_wvbg0\vpnotebook\vpnotebook\__init__.py", line 72, in run
        run_kernel_install(False)
      File "C:\Users\Zachary\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-dx_wvbg0\vpnotebook\vpnotebook\__init__.py", line 63, in run_kernel_install
        install_kernel_spec(source_dir, kernel_name='vpython', user=user)
    NameError: free variable 'install_kernel_spec' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\zachary\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Zachary\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-dx_wvbg0\\vpnotebook\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Zachary\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-3q5u2e2l-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Zachary\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-dx_wvbg0\vpnotebook\
```

Comment: Maybe you have to fix your dependencies?

Comment: Post the rest of the output on Pastebin or the like and I'll edit it into the question with my reputation powers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in `vpnotebook`, upon which `vpython` depends.  Trying to install `vpnotebook` in both Python 2.7 and 3.5 fails with the same error, which appears to have been caused by the package's authors not even using a basic linter.  I would suggest reporting this to said authors, but [there are no contact details, repositories, or project websites listed on the package's PyPI page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/vpnotebook/0.1.3).

Answer (score 4):

The immediate fix is to install jupyter before you install vpnotebook:

```
pip install jupyter
```

Thanks for reporting this; in the future issues posted at either the location @user1114907 indicated or at the main github repo: https://github.com/BruceSherwood/vpython-jupyter/issues

Answer (score 0):

**If your python version is greater than 2.7.9, skip to step 3**

1. Install python version > 2.7.9 [2.7.14 is the latest]

   - Download latest version of python
   - extract the archive
   - `./configure`
   - `make`
   - `make install`
2. Download and re-install pip

   - `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py`
   - `sudo python get-pip.py`
3. Install jupyter First

   - `sudo pip install jupyter`
4. Then, install vpython

   - `sudo pip install vpython`

[Post-installation Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmyyO.png)